# Fetch CSV data using AJAX and render as HTML table with show / hide button

Tags: ajax, html-table, import-from-csv

I've been able to get [this far](http://www.wiberger.se/templates/in-stock.htm).
Now my problem is how to render that ";" delimited CSV file as a two column HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

Use the split() method of the Javascript String object: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

E.g. something like (without any error handling):

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
  var tableHtml = "<table>";
  var lines = xmlhttp.responseText.split("\n");
  for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    tableHtml += "<tr>";
    var line = lines[i].split(";");
    tableHtml += "<td>" + line[0] + "</td><td>" + line[1] + "</td>";
    tableHtml += "</tr>";
  }
  tableHtml += "</table>";
  document.getElementById("stock-table").innerHTML = tableHtml;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jozef. Do you (or anyone else) know how to modify  tableHtml += "<td>" + line[0] + "</td><td>" + line[1] + "</td>"; if you don't know the number of delimiters? Or do I have to use a different approach?

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of fields on one line, or may it vary? Should the table columns have their headers?

Personally, I'd recommend you to take a look at the [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html) JavaScript library and try to play a bit with it. It is well documented, with a nice tutorials.

Comment: There will be anything from 2 to 10 fields, but not more than 10. Preferably the script would create the headers.